# How to change font size on all pages using XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, font-size, textblock

I am working on a windows store app using c# and XAML. I want people to be able to change the text size in my "settings" menu all across the application (on several pages). So far I have found a solution, but it only works with the current TextBlock that I have bound to a slider.

I can change the font size of a single textblock in XAML like this: With a simple textblock using a binding on fontsize bound to the slider:

```
    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Change my font size." VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="277" Width="430" FontSize="{Binding Value, ElementName=TextSlider}"/>    

    <Slider x:Name="TextSlider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="160,113,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Value="14" Minimum="1" Maximum="42" />
```

What I want to do is to bind the font size of all my TextBlock's to a single slider at my settings page. So when you slide the slider, the size of the text changes accordingly to the value of the slider on all pages.
Thank you, I would appreciate any tips on how to do this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a ["DoubleViewModel" (click to see more)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144519/gridview-with-2-columns-fill-width/23145424#23145424) - a `{StaticResource}` in your `App.Resources` dictionary that all `FontSize` properties in your app bind to and your slider's `Value` `TwoWay`-binds to. Then sliding the slider will update all the sizes.

Comment: I can't get it to work, but I have just changed the text size to 22 in app.xaml instead of the slider thing now. Too advanced for such a simple thing :P