# How to arrange images in two columns windows phone 8.1?

Tags: windows, listview, windows-phone-8

I am getting images from a web service. I need to arrange these images in a two column manner. I am using listview and binding these images to listview. But I am getting only one column. How do I put images two column manner?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this question:

[GridView with 2 columns, fill width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144519/gridview-with-2-columns-fill-width)

This should solve your issue.